# Add 8 registers for 0008 and keep the rest a 6 registers

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm converting a .dat to a csv. Everything works but I need to add 8 registers for 0008 and keep the rest a 6. Here is the .dat file:

0004|IP

0006|IP

0008|IP

except there are no blank lines

Here is my code:

```
logging.debug("option 1 selected")
        #check if file exists
        exists = os.path.isfile('stores.dat')

        if exists:
            print('creating phone book')
            with open('stores.dat', 'r') as input_file:
                #open stores.dat
                lines = input_file.readlines()
                newLines = [] # new line array
                for line in lines:

                    registers2 = 21 #for the while loop


                    while registers2 <= 30:  #while loop for selection 1, suppposed to print 6 registers for each store

                        if registers2 < 27:

                            stores = line[:4] #truncates the stores.dat after 4 chars



                            registers = stores + "\Registers" , 'Register ' + str(registers2),IP,'Store ' + stores.strip('0') + '' + ' - Register ' + str(registers2), '', "LAN (TCP)", '', '', '', '','','', '', '', '0x1'

                            newLines.append(registers)




                        registers2 = registers2 + 1

            with open('file.csv', 'w',newline='') as output_file:
                file_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
                file_writer.writerows(newLines)
                print('phonebook saved as file.csv')
        else:
            print('stores.dat does not exist')
```

IPs is changed for security. As you can see the while loop runs 8 times but it adds 6 registers for each store as it should. If you could help me by making it able to add stores that have 8 registers in the future (so not a one time thing). Thanks

This is the current output:

```
 0004\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 4 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0004\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 4 - Register 22,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0004\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 4 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0004\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 4 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0004\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 4 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0004\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 4 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0006\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 6 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0006\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 6 - Register 22,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0006\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 6 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0006\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 6 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0006\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 6 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0006\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 6 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 8 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 8 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 8 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 8 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 8 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 8 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
```

desired output

```
 0004\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 4 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0004\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 4 - Register 22,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0004\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 4 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0004\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 4 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0004\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 4 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0004\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 4 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0006\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 6 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0006\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 6 - Register 22,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0006\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 6 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0006\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 6 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0006\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 6 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0006\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 6 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 8 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 8 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 8 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 8 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 8 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 8 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 27,IP,Store 8 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
 0008\Registers,Register 28,IP,Store 8 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
```

Comment: Hi @krazekidg and welcome to stack overflow. Please try to create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example so we can understand the issue here. It is unlikely that someone reads your code and tries to understand the issue as it is not possible to get it from your explanations.

Comment: Your input file is already a csv (or dsv file to be exact) and can be read with the csv module if you set the delimiter to |

Comment: @CorentinLimier I made the code more simple and added the output

Comment: @CorentinLimier the input is a .dat

Comment: Please add the desired output.

Comment: @CorentinLimier done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('stores.dat') as csvinput, open('file.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvinput, delimiter="|") # Your input can be read with csv module
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvoutput)

    # For each line of stores.dat
    for input_line in csvreader:
        if input_line[0] == "0008":
            # Create 8 registers if first field is 0008
            registers = range(21, 29)
        else:
            # Create 6 registers
            registers = range(21, 27)

        # Write one line per register per input line
        for register in registers:
            output_line =  ["{}\Registers".format(input_line[0]),
                            "Register {}".format(register),
                            line[1], #IP
                            "Store {} - Register {}".format(int(input_line[0]), register),
                            None,
                            "LAN (TCP)",
                            None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,
                            "0x01"]
            csvwriter.writerow(output_line)
```

Content of file.csv :

```
0004\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 4 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0004\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 4 - Register 22,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0004\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 4 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0004\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 4 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0004\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 4 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0004\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 4 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0006\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 6 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0006\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 6 - Register 22,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0006\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 6 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0006\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 6 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0006\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 6 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0006\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 6 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 8 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 8 - Register 22,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 8 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 8 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 8 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 8 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 27,IP,Store 8 - Register 27,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 28,IP,Store 8 - Register 28,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
```